# Installation of php5-gmp on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

Is there a way to find and install the php5-gmp module on Ubuntu 16.04? I looked for this [repository](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) but I can't find it here. In fact, when I tried to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-gmp
```

The results is:

```
Unable to find php5-gmp package
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `php5.6-gmp`:

```
sudo apt install php5.6-gmp
```

Obvously this will only install `gmp` extension for PHP5.6.
If you want it to 7.0, use the right package name:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-gmp
```

Comment: Also, use this command:
`sudo phpenmod gmp`
then restart/reload the web server.